# When Upgrade script its give error in magento 2

Tags: magento2

When i run script using this command `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` its gives this error

> [ErrorException]   array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be
>   array, null given
>
> setup:upgrade [--keep-generated] [--magento-init-params="..."]

In my module i am not using `array_key_exists` why this error generate,How to solve this error?

Installschema:

```
namespace Example\Blog\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;


class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{

public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $installer = $setup;

    $installer->startSetup();

    $table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
        $installer->getTable('blog_post')
    )->addColumn(
        'blogpost_id',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
        null,
        ['identity' => true, 'unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
        'Blog Post ID'
    )->addColumn(
        'title',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        255,
       ['nullable' => false],
        'Title'
    )->addColumn(
        'url_key',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        255,
        ['nullable' => false],
        'URL key'
    )->addColumn(
        'content',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        '2M',
        ['nullable' => false],
        'Content'
    )->addColumn(
        'short_content',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        '2M',
        ['nullable' => false],
        'Short Content'
    )->addColumn(
        'image',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        255,
        ['nullable' => false],
        'Featured Image'
    )->addColumn(
        'image_thumb',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        255,
        ['nullable' => false],
        'Thumb Image'
    )->addColumn(
        'category',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        255,
       ['nullable' => false],
        'category'
    )->addColumn(
        'tags',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        null,
        ['nullable' => false],
        'Tags'
    )->addColumn(
        'meta_title',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        '2M',
        ['nullable' => false],
        'Meta Keywords'
    )->addColumn(
        'meta_keywords',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        '2M',
        ['nullable' => false],
        'Meta Keywords'
    )->addColumn(
        'meta_description',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        null,
        ['nullable' => false],
        'Meta Description'
    )->addColumn(
        'publish_date',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_DATE,
        null,
        [],
        'Publish Date'
    )->addColumn(
        'is_active',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
        null,
        [],
        'Active Status'
    )->addColumn(
        'created_at',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
        null,
        [],
        'Creation Time'
    )->addColumn(
        'update_time',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
        null,
        [],
        'Modification Time'
    )->addColumn(
        'views',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
        null,
        ['nullable' => false],
        'Views'
    )->addColumn(
        'store_id',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        255,
        null,
        ['nullable' => false],
        'Store ID'
    )

    ->setComment(
        'Blog Table'
    );

    $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
    $installer->endSetup();

  }
  }
```

Comment: post your upgradeschema here

Comment: I am not upgrade my module i am install my module

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem is in below line in **fourth argument** ,Fourth argument must be array

```
->addColumn(
        'store_id',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        255,
        null,
        ['nullable' => false],
        'Store ID'
    )
```

It should be

```
->addColumn(
            'store_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            255,
            ['nullable' => false],
            'Store ID'
        )
```

When you look at this

```
  public function addColumn($name, $type, $size = null, $options = [], $comment = null)
```

This function accept **fourth argument** as array thats why it create issue in your setup script.